# How to Add multiple files from different folders in same file input in html or php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

How to Add multiple files from different folders in same file input in html or php 
i want to multiple files from different folders using file input it is possible. and if it is possible then how??

Comment: Use `multiple` attribute. Check this : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: show what you've done, some code block.

Comment: i want to like dropzone but image is not uploaded in sever

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to do just by merely using the `<input type="file">` with the ' 'multiple' keyword. This by itself will only allow attaching multiple files from same folder.
To complete your requirement, you will probably have to resort to using jQuery along with JavaScript and HTML, to provide an additional 'Upload' button after one or more files from the same folder are attached. This way you can attach any additional files from other folders and provide some sort of a 'Save' button, to eventually attach all files and save the result.